# Convert many variables in a dataframe from numeric to factor

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to modify a dataframe by converting multiple integer variables to factors.

A simple dataframe for illustrative purposes is the following:

```
mydf<-data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20, z=21:30)
```

Let's say I would like to change the first two columns from int to factor.
In order to achieve this I could write

```
mydf[,1] <- as.factor(mydf[,1])
mydf[,2] <- as.factor(mydf[,2])
```

This piece code works but if I have to change many columns, I will have to repeat this piece of code many times. I have tried

```
mydf[,c(1,2)]<-as.factor(mydf[,c(1,2)])
```

but the output is

```
str(mydf)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
$ x: chr  "1:10" "11:20" "1:10" "11:20" ...
$ y: chr  "1:10" "11:20" "1:10" "11:20" ...
$ z: int  21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

How can I achieve my target in a more elegant and neat way? Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me: 

data[cols] <- lapply(data[cols], factor)